# When GETting a list of products via Shopify API, how does pagination work on the server side?

Tags: api, shopify

Scenario: Store with 1000 products; need to download them all. Requests for products are limited to a maximum of 250 products per call, and apparently the API may or may not return the "limit" requested.  For example, a call with limit=250 may return less than 250 items, from what I've observed. So, to get 1000 products a minimum of 4 calls are needed.

The following requests are issued:

```
#1  GET /admin/products.xml?limit=250&page=1 (returned the first 250 products 1-250)
#2  GET /admin/products.xml?limit=250&page=2 (returned the next 250 products 251-500)
#3  GET /admin/products.xml?limit=250&page=3 (****returned only 200 products 501-700**)
#4  GET /admin/products.xml?limit=250&page=4 (****what does it return here?**)
```

So, the question is about pagination on the server, which will define what happens in line #4 above:

1) Does the API perform smart pagination, in which it knows that the previous request returned only 200 products and therefore the next page must return a list starting with product number 701?

or

2) Does it perform blind pagination, in which a request for page 4 will always start with product number 751, regardless of what happened in the last call?

Comment: If call 3 only returned 200 wouldn't that mean there is only 700 products and call 4 would return nothing?

Comment: @JohnDuff: I guess what I need is confirmation of what you just wrote, that EOF is the ONLY reason a call with limit=250 would return less than 250 items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the /admin/products/count.json to get the count of all products. Then divide that number by 250 to get the total amount of pages.

Comment: Hmm, interesting solution. Wish they would just include page/limit/current page data in their response.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass params in shopify API using [shopify api gem](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api) if in rails or can directly use Shopify APIs for send params.

```
ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, params: { page: parmas[:page], 
                                         limit: 10, 
                                         title: params[:search]
                                       })
```