# How to get /admin/products.json in a chronological order?

Tags: shopify

I need to be able to poll more than 250 products from the Shopify API. In order to do so, I need to retrieve the products from the API in a chronological order, with the oldest products first. Once I have the first 250 items, I retrieve another 250 items filtered by `max_created_at`.

I noticed that: `GET /admin/products.json` returns the products in a random order, but `GET /admin/products.json?since_id=0` returns the products in a chronological order. Is this the intended behaviour? Or is there a flag that I can send with `GET /admin/products.json` to specify the sorting order?

**Edit:** I guess my question boils down to this: Is there a field that I can set that the results returned by the Shopify API will be ordered by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unintended behaviour, reliable sort orders for Product are limited to title and total, and then filtering options are as listed in the [API docs](http://api.shopify.com/product.html).

Comment: OK but that leaves me with a huge problem: What if the user has 1000 products and I need to retrieve them all via the API? I can only get 250 at a time. For the orders, I would do the following: Receive the first 250, and since they are ordered by `created_at`, with the oldest order returned last, I would run another query with `created_at_max` for any orders OLDER than the last one in the first result set. How can I do the same with products?

Comment: Addendum: Never mind, I just figured out that I can use the `page` parameter to paginate through results, as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249196/when-getting-a-list-of-products-via-shopify-api-how-does-pagination-work-on-the

Comment: The `page` parameter is deprecated and will is scheduled to be removed on 2020-04-01.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the API has been updated since the last post but now you can do that like that :

```
https://yourshop.myshopift.com/admin/products.json?limit=50&fields=id,images,title&order=created_at+desc
```

Just add the query string parameter order=created_at+asc

This is an undocumented feature but it seems to work for most fields.